# Wrapping tags around a cursor in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a `contenteditable` `article` tag

```
<article id="content" contenteditable="true">
   <p class="default-text"> Write here </p>
</article>
```

I have this jquery to remove the `p` tag with class `.default-text` when article is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '#content', function() {
   $('.default-text').remove();
});
//Here i want to wrap a new <p> </p> as the user starts typing.
```

Basically, I'm trying to replicate the placeholder text effect on input fields by removing the default text.
I also want the contents of what's written in the article tag to be wrapped around a p tag.
How do i go about this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *around the cursor*

Comment: Around the cursor mean ? you want to place your new element nearby the cursor position ?

Comment: when the user types #content, there has to be a p tag wrapped around the text after the article tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$(document).on('click keyup', '#content', function() {
   if($('.default-text').remove()) {
       if(this.children().length === 0 {
            document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will solve your issue...............

**HTML**

```
<article id="content">
   <p class="default-text" contenteditable="true"> Write here </p>
</article>
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.default-text', function() {
   $('.default-text').text('');
    $(this).removeClass('default-text');
});
```

The output is as per your requirement.

Comment: Yup, a good idea. I've tried something like that by wrapping the default text in a span tag and removing the span, but the problem is, when i hit backspace twice in the contenteditable article it removes the p tag entirely.